# Concurrent request - Codeigniter or Apache 2.4 or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, apache2

I'm building a system that has control pane, for admin stuffs and public area, that everyone can see. Like a portal.

Well, the admin user must do some operation that can take 40 seconds of processing. In this operation user must upload several (>180) images, and the system will create a small version of each.

While a ran this operation, I opened another tab and try to reach home page (public content). For my surprise (or not) the page only load, after the other tab concluded the work.

I know that could be something related to the database, but I don't know how to track this, Or it could be something related to the apache (? don't think so...).

**Important**: Is not mandatory to wait the long processing finish.

In both cases, how can I find the issue here?

Environment

- Codeigniter 3.0.6 (with HMVC)
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Was an transaction started with CodeIgniter.

I remove the automated transaction and just check if all scripts were OK. If not I just delete them.